# Which chromium c++ function gets triggerd when calling element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(''))?

Tags: javascript, c++, debugging, chromium

I set breakpoints in: 
*third_party/blink/renderer/core/dom/events/*

*mouse_event.cc
*event.cc
*event_target.cc
*simulated_event_util.cc

but it don't reaches any file, function or breakpoint.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The Blink runs is a renderer process, not the browser process. You should attach to one or more renderer processes and then debug it

Comment: I understood the problem, thank you very much.

Comment: You should use `content_shell` to debug renderer processes. You have to generate that file by ninja